# adding frame with options to menu button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I add a frame to the left side of the website with options after pressing the menu button?

here is the relevant html

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
   <div class="bar1"></div>
   <div class="bar2"></div>
   <div class="bar3"></div>
```

here is the relevant css

```
    .container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
```

Here is the relevant JS

```
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code, I got the following error message: "ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

One solution is to skip the function call and move your toggle code directly inside the onclick parameter.

```
<div class="container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('change')">
   <div class="bar1"></div>
   <div class="bar2"></div>
   <div class="bar3"></div>
```

Here's a working example of this: https://jsfiddle.net/k84vcbu2/

Note: the onclick parameter is generally discouraged, because it mixes JavaScript into your HTML. Perhaps the best approach is to drop the onclick parameter from your HTML and assign the click event from JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('container1').addEventListener('click',function () {
   this.classList.toggle('change')
   })
```

And here's the edited HTML (I removed the "onclick" parameter and added an "id" parameter)

```
<div class="container" id="container1">
   <div class="bar1"></div>
   <div class="bar2"></div>
   <div class="bar3"></div>
```

Comment: Hm, not sure I quite get where you are going at

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were having trouble with. Can you expand on what you mean by "how do I add a frame to the left side of the website with options after pressing the menu button?"